# Google Cloud Run has no available instances?

Tags: google-cloud-run

I have encountered this error frequently from Oct/11/2019.

> The request was aborted because there was no available instance.

So I deploy to cloud run, I can't access to the service.
and always display

```
>Error: Server Error
>The server encountered an error and could not complete your request.
>Please try again in 30 seconds.
```

What happened on cloud run instances?
Is this correct behavior?

I know this error is posted to [troubleshooting](https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/troubleshooting#abort-request) .
But I have never encountered this error until recently.
So I can't understand why I got this error suddenly.

Comment: Please check this related question [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57007386/how-to-fix-cloudrun-error-the-request-was-aborted-because-there-was-no-availabl/57013896).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to fix CloudRun error 'The request was aborted because there was no available instance'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57007386/how-to-fix-cloudrun-error-the-request-was-aborted-because-there-was-no-availabl)

Comment: You have not provided enough detail about your use case to provide an answer. We can only provide tips and guesses. For example, is this the only request, did you have a sudden burst of traffic, how long does your container take to start responding (cold starts), etc? Additional information that might help is the log entries from Stackdriver.

Comment: There another case if you set the `max-instances` param too low according with your traffic.

Comment: yes, i set `max-instances` before I encountered this error. but I set enought instances(=5) and concurrency(=5). cloud run can't serve just 1 request at that time. but now, the error doesn't happend.(maybe it's due to beta test.)